# Zone.js in Angular 6

Tags: typescript, jhipster, angular6, zone.js

I created an application with jhipster. It is working but when I make a request to backend side I get 401(Unauthorized) error with zone.js. I think my code is working but I think that I have a general error.

I made some researches about zone.js but I could not find any solution. Do you have any idea?

Comment: No one can be in an efficient help unless you provide what did you really try. I recommend you to take some time to read [mcve].

Comment: You will get a 401 error by default unless you log in and authenticate, the page requests the current user's account information on load and returns 401 if not logged in

Comment: This error has nothing to do with zone.js, just like @JonRuddell said, it is because you are not log in or not authorized.

Comment: thank you very much.I found solution.Solution is to allow all users to reach urls in securityConfiguration.java.I have rearranged this file.